# Loading Data Table on form load, how to speed it up in c#

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, .net-3.5

i have c# windows form when it opens it load thousands of record to fill a data table, the problem is when i click on the form it show a blank window for some time before displaying all the data, So

How do i display a wait sign on the datagridview while the data load and let the form's other control to be visible?

how can i speed it  i am ready to do threading if it does the job.

Comment: Is using jQuery an option? The you can do all this (the async loading of the table and loader image) with jQuery. How many rows of that 1000's do you want to display on the page, if you only want a selection you can use a pageddatasource

Comment: @Ivo, it's winforms, not html/web - so no jQuery.

Comment: @Ivo: [see](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492)

Comment: sorry was to much in my "own" world, but the pagedatasource is still an option i think

Comment: Are you doing any formatting to the DataGridView? Usually fetching some thousands of records from backend should be done in less than a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a background thread. You could set up a BackgroundWorker in your form, or set up a basic asynchronous model with a BeginInvoke in your event handler, which will be given another method as its callback when done. In the background worker, do all your data retrieval, and then Invoke back to the main thread when you need to actually populate the DGV (which should take much less time once the information is all in memory).

The problem is that while the main thread is busy waiting for the DB to come back with all the rows, the system cannot respond to any other user input or Windows messages (such as "redraw yourself"). Windows will see that the message queue for that app is backing up and mark the app as "not responding". Not a very pleasant user experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely use threading for that. It basically consists on starting another thread to query the database while you display some loading message to your user.

Heres some documentation:

[MSDN Thread Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)

And some code example:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
t.Start();
```

Where ThreadProc should be your Data Loading Method.

Let me clarify a little more:

Your Data Loading method should only query the database and supply the return to the main Thread, as pointed out in comments, you cannot interact with UI elements from another Thread.

Comment: Be careful if you're updating controls on the form though, you're going to need to invoke, your thread is not able to talk to your UI thread

Comment: @Hammerstein Nice pointing, I've edited the answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

use backgroundworker component. Its easier to handle it than threading on is own 
Alternatively, you can use async methods provided by ado.net such as beginexecutereader etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use [asynchronous queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szdt0kc%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) in combination with partial results.

If your database system does not support the LIMIT-clause common in MySQL to specify partial results, you can use an approach like [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/Coffeehouse/102407-SQL-Server-and-LIMIT-clauses-on-SELECT-statements/).